# Add controls to a collection and update from collection

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, collections, web-controls

I have an ASP.NET app with lots of textboxes all over the page that need updating at various points through program execution.

These textboxes actually belong to a certain class, so for easy updating I thought I could create a Dictionary(Of string, object) and add the `control.ID` and the `control` to it and then for updating do something like this:

(in case of updating textbox.text):

```
for each kv as KeyValuePair(Of string, object) in mytextboxes
      if (kv.Key.Contains("textboxid")) then
             DirectCast(kv.Value, TextBox).Text = mystring
      end if
next
```

However the text property of the textbox does not actually get updated.  I'm mainly trying to avoid having to manually do `textbox.text = somestring` for each one of my textboxes every time I have to update them.

Is this a feasible solution that could be made to work?
If so, what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function needs to cast the control directly, not a KeyValuePair collection.  Try something like this...

```
Private Sub SetTextboxText(ByVal strTextBoxID As String, ByVal strText As String)

    Dim txtChangeThisOne As TextBox = CType(Page.FindControl(strTextBoxID), TextBox)

    If Not txtChangeThisOne Is Nothing Then

        txtChangeThisOne.Text = strText

    End If

End Sub
```

Then to call...

```
SetTextboxText("TextboxID", "Text you wish to set.")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use a dictionary, try this:

```
Dim mytextboxes As New Dictionary(Of String, TextBox)
Dim mystring As String = "A Input String."
Dim myTextBoxName As String = "TextBox1"
Dim t As TextBox
For Each c As Object In Me.Controls
    If (TypeOf c Is TextBox) Then
        t = CType(c, TextBox)
        mytextboxes.Add(t.Name, t)
    End If
Next

Try
    mytextboxes(myTextBoxName).Text = mystring
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("There is no " & myTextBoxName)
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a project that uses 100 buttons and they share one event handler. If you could create all of the TextBoxes in an Array, you may be able to define a common event handler. The following snippit would be used as a reference. Hope the VB code is still helpful.
If you want to test the code, you need to have a Form and a Layout of 10 X 10. Let me know if it helps.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private NRow As Integer = 10
    Private NCol As Integer = 10
    Private BtnArray(NRow * NCol - 1) As Button
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        TableLayoutPanel1.Size = Me.ClientSize
        For i As Integer = 0 To BtnArray.Length - 1
            BtnArray(i) = New Button()
            BtnArray(i).Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top Or AnchorStyles.Bottom Or AnchorStyles.Left Or AnchorStyles.Right
            BtnArray(i).Text = CStr(i)
            TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(BtnArray(i), i Mod NCol, i \ NCol)
            AddHandler BtnArray(i).Click, AddressOf ClickHandler
        Next
    End Sub
    Public Sub ClickHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        MsgBox("I am button #" & CType(sender, Button).Text)
    End Sub
End Class
```